# Is there a way of changing the format of the errors of php's error_log(string)?

Tags: php, error-handling

i'd like tout know wether or not it is possible to change the default error format in php_error.log :

```
[12-Aug-2015 23:11:23 Europe/Berlin] information
```

to something else which I could reuse more easily like :

```
timestamp;information;otherinformation
```

without using set error handler.

Comment: sure, hack up the php source code. other than enabling/disabling html in error messages, there's no direct control over the format.

Comment: it is not for displaying them differently in html, but in the logs. (i'll add that to the post)

Comment: i see no substantive difference between the current format and what you want

Comment: this would be more verboose :

    `timestamp;information;otherinformation`

the ";" are important as well !

Comment: so `;` vs `]` is important?

Comment: indeed, as semantically `]` holds a specific semantic : there has been a `[` opened before. Moreover, I do this as I try to make-up a standard for my website, and navigating threw errors looking for `;` more adapted then, especially when it comes to writing the errors :
(blabla ] blabla2) isn't very understandable by humans, i think.

Comment: your just looking to make things difficult - good luck with that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to [define your own error handler](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php):

```
function myErrorHandler($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline)
{
    if (!(error_reporting() & $errno)) {
        // This error code is not included in error_reporting
        return;
    }

    switch ($errno) {
    case E_USER_ERROR:
        echo "<b>My ERROR</b> [$errno] $errstr<br />\n";
        echo "  Fatal error on line $errline in file $errfile";
        echo ", PHP " . PHP_VERSION . " (" . PHP_OS . ")<br />\n";
        echo "Aborting...<br />\n";
        exit(1);
        break;

    case E_USER_WARNING:
        echo "<b>My WARNING</b> [$errno] $errstr<br />\n";
        break;

    case E_USER_NOTICE:
        echo "<b>My NOTICE</b> [$errno] $errstr<br />\n";
        break;

    default:
        echo "Unknown error type: [$errno] $errstr<br />\n";
        break;
    }

    /* Don't execute PHP internal error handler */
    return true;
}

// function to test the error handling
function scale_by_log($vect, $scale)
{
    if (!is_numeric($scale) || $scale <= 0) {
        trigger_error("log(x) for x <= 0 is undefined, you used: scale = $scale", E_USER_ERROR);
    }

    if (!is_array($vect)) {
        trigger_error("Incorrect input vector, array of values expected", E_USER_WARNING);
        return null;
    }

    $temp = array();
    foreach($vect as $pos => $value) {
        if (!is_numeric($value)) {
            trigger_error("Value at position $pos is not a number, using 0 (zero)", E_USER_NOTICE);
            $value = 0;
        }
        $temp[$pos] = log($scale) * $value;
    }

    return $temp;
}

// set to the user defined error handler
$old_error_handler = set_error_handler("myErrorHandler");
```

Now, you're [error_log](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-log.php) calls will use the defined format.